# what are the limitations of mobile phones and web development

Tags: png, mobile-website, mobile-phones

simple really.. I am have been asked to do a mobile site (straight html + css (+ maybe jquery mobile later on)). The site will need to support the new type smart phone and the old type Nokia/(Symbian OS) with the web browser. Doubts and reservations aside as to anyone without a smart phone would bother visiting this site it still needs to support it.

My first question is do older phones support PNG images and transparancey... But this has led me to a much broader question of what are some of the limitations of developing for older phone platforms is there anything that has caught mobile web devs out and had them scratching their head for an afternoon..

what are the limitations of mobile phones?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly which phones you need to support you could be in for some headaches.

A few of the things you need to consider:

You need to consider a massive variety of screen sizes.

Large screens will be able to show bigger images but smaller screens will require smaller versions of images.

Yes, as you suspect, not all browsers support all image formats.

Do you need to support touch screen and non touch screen devices? If you do, you'll need to consider the size of items that need to be touched.

Users normally want different things from mobile verisons of websites. You should build the mobile version with this different context in mind.

Different mobile browsers have their own quirks with regard to rendering HTML.

It's safest to assume no javascript support except in the latest smartphones. If you go back further than that the support is inconsistent at best.

CSS support also varies across browsers. Avoid trying to do anything clever with CSS.

Some older browsers also don't support CSS or JS in separate files.

You need to be aware of different doctypes that different browsers require.

A single, vertically scrolling layout, is usually best for mobile web pages.

Optimize everything for performance. Phones are less powerful at processing what's downloaded and data is very likley to take longer to download than compared with a PC on broadband.

And test on actual devices. Especially for older devices.

Answer (score 0):

Some older phones do support PNG, some don't.

Some older phones support PNG with transparency, some don't.

If you absolutely must have images that look good, save them with a background colour that matches the site, and as a JPG - then you've got the best of both worlds.

For newer phones - go for it with PNG transparency support.